# How to find side by side 11 digits in a string in PHP?

Tags: php

i have too many strings are not in a general pattern. All has digits but i need have to get which contains 11 character "numbers only" in this string. For example:

```
"John Doe 12345 12345678910 123456789123456 12:22:54 Transfer from atm"
"John Doe 12:22:54 123456789123456 Transfer from atm 12345678910"
```

for these string I have to get "12345678910" only. So there is no general pattern. And string can contain numbers moren than 11 character. So I have get only 11 character numbers! How can I do that in php?

Comment: Try a regular expression

Answer (score 1):

You can use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to get you desired 11 digits :

```
<?php

$string = '"John Doe No:12345 Id:12345678910 Key:123456789123456 12:22:54 Transfer from atm"';

if(preg_match('#(\D|\b)([\d]{11})(\D|\b)#', $string, $matches) != false){
    print_r($matches[2]);
}
```

Output

```
12345678910
```

**Regular Expression Explained** :

`(\D|\b)`: `\D` means **non-numeric** character, `\b` means word boundary. `|` is *OR* operator. so this group will match either non-numeric character or word boundary. (start of string, space)

`([\d]{11})`: `\d` means numeric digit. {11} suggests we match digit only 11 times, no more no less. This is the main group we need to capture.

`(\D|\b)`: Repeat of first group just to support end of string or word boundary.

**`$matches[2]`** will always hold the desired 11 digit.

Comment: You're almost there. It doesn't recognize 11-digit numbers at the beginning and at the end of the string.

Comment: Because regular expressions are mysterious for many people it would be great to also explain the meaning of each piece you use to construct it (i.e. `\D`, `\d`, `[]`, `{11}`, parentheses, etc.)

Comment: maybe `\b\d{11}\b` ?

Comment: Yeah, used `\D` and `\b` to support start and end of string. trying to write some explanation now.

Answer (score -1):

From your question, You need to extract 11 digit number.

1. Pass the string though a regex and extract all sub-strings that are numeric,
2. Loop through the matches and get the number whose length is 11 characters.

   ```
   $str = "John Doe 12345 12345678910 123456789123456 12:22:54 Transfer from atm";

   preg_match_all('/\d+/', $str, $matches);

   $_value= null;

   foreach($matches[0] as $value){

   if(strlen($value)==11)
       $_value = $value;
   }
   print_r($_value);
   ```

Comment: This answer is even worse than other similar answer.